Owl-carousel dots are duplicated on iphone
As you can see it on the attached photo, my owl-carousel dots are dupliacted, and also going under each other, on iPhone.

On pc, and other phones, everything works nice, there are just 2-3 dots, and the are next to each other, in a row.
I didnt modify nothing in the owl-carousel css, its original from github.
$('.owl-carousel-termekek').owlCarousel({
    loop:true,
    margin:20,
    autoplay:true,
    autoplayTimeout:5000,
    autoplayHoverPause:true,
    autoplaySpeed:1000,
    responsiveClass:true,
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:2,
            nav:false,
            dots:true
        },
        600:{
            items:3,
            nav:false,
            dots:true
        },
        1000:{
            items:4,
            nav:true,
            dots:true,
            loop:true
        },
        1400:{
            items:6,
            loop:true,
            nav:false,
            dots:true
        }
    }
});


Please provide a proper [mre] of the issue.

What version of iPhone browser? Maybe it's very old and unsupported?
